# Question regarding embedding variables in double-quoted strings in PHP

Tags: php

Are the following instructions equivalent?

```
# 1
$str = "$var1$var2</td>";

# 2
$str = "$var1" . "$var2" . "</td>";
```

---

**EDIT:** Thank you all.

`header('Location:`[Question regarding anonymous methods as class members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686724/question-regarding-anonymous-methods-as-class-members)`);`

Comment: The second one is better written as `$str = $var1 . $var2 . "</td>";` . `"$var"` is of no use here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, but within a string it's recommended to contain the vars in `{}`:

```
$str = "{$var1}{$var2}</td>";
```

This is also useful because it allows you to do things like:

```
$str = "{$obj1->getName()}{$obj1->getDescription()}</td>";
```

Comment: Personally I find `$str = $obj1->getName() . $obj1->getDescription() . "</td>"` more readable.

Comment: i'd use the {} to do something like this "{$row['name']}".

Answer (score 2):

You end up with the same string but the double quotes around each variable is superfluous. You could eliminate them and have:

```
$str = $var1 . $var2 . '</td>';
```

Most syntax highlighters color variables outside of strings different than strings, making it easier to scan.

Comment: I'd also suggest using single quotes around </td> as there's nothing there to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are equivalant. When writing strings and putting variables in them, it is always preferable to write whatever is most readable (and actually works) by you or the team you work with. Ignore anyone who talks about time taken to parse single quoted strings Vs double quoted strings, this is micro-optimisation and the Root Of All Evil.