# Question regarding anonymous methods as class members

Tags: php, anonymous-methods

I am developing a PHP mini-framework, one of whose methods builds an HTML table from an array of objects:

```
class HTMLTableField {
    private $hdr;
    private $alg;
    private $fun;

    function __construct($descr, $align, $apply) {
        # fun must be an anonymous function
        $this->hdr = '<th>' . htmlentities($descr) . "</th>\n";     
        $this->alg = "<td style=\"text-align: {$align}\">";
        $this->fun = $apply;
    }

    function getHeader() {
        return $this->hdr;
    }

    function getCell($row) {
        # This line fails
        return "{$this->alg}{$this->fun($row)}</td>";
    }
}

function gen_html_table($rows, $fields) {
    # $fields must be an array of HTMLTableField objects
    echo "<table>\n<thead>\n<tr>\n";
    foreach ($fields as $field)
        echo $field->getHeader();
    echo "</tr>\n</thead>\n<tbody>\n";
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo "<tr>\n";
        foreach ($fields as $field)
            echo $field->getCell($row);
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</tbody>\n</table>\n";
}
```

However, when the flow of control of `gen_html_table` reaches

```
echo $field->getCell($row);
```

I get an error: "Call to undefined method HTMLTableField::fun()." But fun is supposed to be an anonymous method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use an anynomious function via the class property.

```
function getCell($row) {
    # This line works
    $fun = $this->fun;
    return $this->alg . $fun($row) . "</td>";
}
```

makes your script running :), tested on php 5.3.1

Comment: Yup, it's what I just did. But it's not very elegant.

Comment: i like to read it more than `call_user_func()`. sadly there is no better way.

Comment: Yeah, `call_user_func()` makes it feel as if reflection weren't native to PHP, but rather hacked into it.

Answer (score 2):

There is even shorter and in my opinion more elegant solution:

```
function getCell($row) {
    return "{$this->alg}{$this->fun->__invoke($row)}</td>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I found an ugly, but ultimately working solution:

```
$func = $this->fun;
return "{$this->alg}{$func($row)}</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are try to accomplish but are you not better off using Magic Methods http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods?

Comment: No, this time magic methods won't help. `fun` is an *anonymous* function.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is:

```
call_user_func($this->fun, $row)
```

I suppose it's a matter of style, but a lot of time using `call_user_func()` or `call_user_func_array()` is considered cleaner than `$func()` syntax, and in some cases (such as this one), necessary. It also makes it easier to spot dynamic calls right away.

Comment: Yeah, but I wish `$($this->fun)($row)` were possible.

Comment: @Eduardo `call_user_func[_array]` is the PHP way.

Comment: I'm a C++ programmer who happens to be using PHP out of necessity. A FORTRAN programmer can write FORTRAN programs in any language. A C++ programmer hates all other languages, because he cannot write C++ programs in them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

```
$this->$fun($row)
```

rather than

```
$this->fun($row)
```

The former calls the function pointer stored in the member variable `$fun`, while the latter calls the member function `fun()`, which as pointed out does not exist.

Comment: Oh. I thought `$fun` was used to use a **string** as the name of a function.

Comment: @Eduardo, it can do that, too, but that's definitely not recommended!

Comment: The left-brained C++ programmer in me wants to use `$($this->fun)`.

Comment: Actually, I kind of suspect your problem is the fact that you're inside a quote, which complicates string parsing. Have you tried teasing out the anonymous function call onto its own line?

Comment: Nope. But I tried extracting the anonymous function into a temporary variable, which worked like a charm.

Comment: @Eduardo, your solution is exactly what I was trying to suggest with my previous comment :).